# Eloquent Relationships - null - Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Estoy tratando de llegar al campo profesiones de la tabla profesiones relacionada a la tabla users a traves de $user->profession en tinker pero me arroja null a pesar de que modifiqué mi modelo User.

```html
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use App\Profession;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    public function profession()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Profession');
    }
}
```

El codigo del Modelo Profession

```html
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Profession extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'profession_id';
    protected $fillable = ['name'];
    protected $table = 'professions';
}
```

El código que he ejecutado en tinker:

```html
$user = User::first();
$user->profession; //null
```

Está demás decir que la relación está creada y las tablas tienen registros
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Que valor tiene profession_id de ese usuario?

Comment: El valor de profesion_id = 1

Comment: Tal vez tengas que indicar explícitamente la llave primaria cuando defines la relación `$this->belongsTo('App\Profession', 'profession_id', 'profession_id');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por lo que veo, en tu modelo Profession, la llave primaria no es "id", con lo cual, al declarar la relación tienes que indicar cuales son los campos en cada tabla. No puedes dejar belongsTo con un solo argumento.

```
  public function profession ()
  {
         return $this->belongsTo('App\Profession', 'profession_id', 'profession_id' );
   }
```

Si no puede formarse la relación por convención de nombres -es decir, que sigan la estructura users.profession_id y professions.id-, necesitas pasar los campos de la relación como segundo y tercer argumento.

Comment: Si mejoras la respuesta, con separacion de parrafos y pones como quedaria los modelos usando codigo, te doy positivol.

Comment: Muchas gracias. Cualquier otra sugerencia será bienvenida.

Comment: Pruebo y te estoy comentando, pensé que con especificarlo en el modelo era suficiente. Gracias.